# show that a vector is on a line

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

can you please explain this question to me?

Show that for any two vectors (vector a) and (vector b), 
the (vector a + vector b)/2 is on the line that connects the vector a and the vector b.
show that (vector a + vector b)/2 is equidistant from vector a and vector b.

thanks, your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be vectors. then $M=\frac{A+B}{2}$ lies on the "line" from $A$ to $B$ if $M-A$ is an element of $Vect(B-A)$. But $M-A=\frac{B-A}{2}$, So that this is clearly true. Note also that $M-A=-(M-B)$, so that $||M-A||=||M-B||$

Comment: can you please re-explain this part, if M-A is an element of Vect(B-A). thanks

Comment: Sure. A point $X$ is on the line from $A$ to $B$ if for some real $t$, $X=A+t(B-A)$, hence $X-A=t(B-A)$. The set $\{t(B-A), t\ real\}$ is precisely $Vect(B-A)$ Explicitely, take $t=\frac{1}{2}$, this gives $M$

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a straight line segment between point $P$ and $Q$ with,

$$
l:\; P + \lambda (Q-P),
$$

since for $\lambda=0$ you are at $P$, for $\lambda=1$ you are at $Q$ and this is a linear function of $\lambda$.

If there is a $\lambda$ that gives $(P+Q)/2$ then it should be on the line.

When considering the distance between two points you can take the difference between those points (the order should not matter) and calculate the length of those. However by playing around with the order you should already be able to show that the distances are the same.

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation, what do you mean by: If there is a λ that gives (P+Q)/2 then it should be on the line.

Comment: @patriciajade The line $l$ defined by the point that follow from from the expression $P+\lambda(Q-P)$ by choosing any value for $\lambda$.